# Horizontal line with fade out effect

Tags: css, less, linear-gradients

I'm trying to replace bootstrap `<hr />` with a gradient looking line like this one.

[image]

So far I've tried used this mixin:

```
.horizontal-gradient (@startColor: #eee, @endColor: white) {
  background-color: @startColor;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(@startColor), to(@endColor));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, @startColor, @endColor);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, @startColor, @endColor);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, @startColor, @endColor);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, @startColor, @endColor);
}
```

but... it didn't work.

**Edit**

I decided to create a separate class (`<hr/>` might be useful the way it is in the future). But, I still can't get this to work...

```css
.post-title-line {
  background-color: #403a41;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#403a41), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #403a41, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #403a41, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #403a41, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #403a41, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-title-line"></div>
```

Comment: Please elaborate *didn't work* and also show us either the compiled CSS output or the way your mixin was invoked. That mixin should work fine if the usage was correct.

Comment: And how exactly you used this mixin? Mixins do not produce any CSS on their own. By default Bootstrap uses minimal [`hr`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.5/less/normalize.less#L212) from common `normalize` goody and it does not invoke any mixins. More over it has the zero height (so even if you set `background-image` for `hr` it stays invisible).

Comment: Ok, I created a separate class, named it `post-title-line`, then added `width: 100%;  height: 1px;  position: relative; `  to it and the mixin. This is the css output http://pastebin.com/cnMsZ7qq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reason:**

Your problem is not with the mixin but the choice of colors. `rgba(0,0,0,0)` is equivalent to `transparent` but you already have a `background-color` set within the selector. So effectively your gradient becomes from `#403a41` to `#403a41` which just results in a solid line.

You can verify this behavior by changing the `background-color` to something else within your selector. In the below snippet, I have set it to red so that you can see what I mean.

```css
.post-title-line {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#403a41), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #403a41, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #403a41, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #403a41, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #403a41, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-title-line"></div>
```

---

**Solution:**

The **ideal solution** would be to modify the mixin code like given below and just use the `background` property. Newer browsers which recognize the gradients will overwrite the first property (solid color) whereas browsers that don't recognize gradients would continue to use it.

```css
.horizontal-gradient (@startColor: #eee, @endColor: white) {
  background: @startColor;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(@startColor), to(@endColor));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, @startColor, @endColor);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, @startColor, @endColor);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, @startColor, @endColor);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, @startColor, @endColor);
}
```

If you **can't alter the mixin**, you could either override the `background-color` (to `transparent`) after the mixin is invoked or set the `endColor` color as `rgba(255,255,255,1)`.

I would recommend the former because `rgba(255,255,255,1)` is equivalent to `white` and might not be suitable when your page background is not white whereas [transparent and `rgba(0,0,0,0)` are the same as per W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparent).

Note that this solution will have an impact on the fallback for old browsers that do not support gradients. They will see nothing instead of a solid line.

```css
.post-title-line {
  background-color: #403a41;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#403a41), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #403a41, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #403a41, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #403a41, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #403a41, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent; /* add this line after the mixin call */
}
```

```html
<div class="post-title-line"></div>
```

Comment: Notice there's [still border around](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/oXoYPR?editors=110), so I suppose one also needs to suppress the border (or `1px` `height` won't be enough because of Bootstrap's `box-sizing: content-box;`).

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Yup, that is default behavior for `hr` based on whatever I have seen but in this case OP is using `div` so it shouldn't be a problem :)

Comment: Ah right, I've missed he's using `<div>` and not `<hr>` , sorry.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Nah, no problems mate. Its nice to have that comment because it may help others who are trying to use with `hr`.

Comment: @Harry : Thanks for your time, it worked. Here's the final result and the reason why I decided to keep the normal `<hr />`. :  http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/350019/7207dd595977ba12d8bc1b78b66ab2b5

Comment: @c4ta1n: Glad to be of help mate. I've just made an update to the answer, please check that out also :)